# Best approach to delete large table with foreign key constraints

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, delete

How to purge a table with a billion records that has foreign key to another table? Should one partition the table and the child table and use partition swap?

Comment: Which side of the key is the table on?

Comment: I recommend to remove the FK and recreate after.

Comment: [As always](http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/).

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik delete with top it's a awesome solution to delete huge amount of dates but if the referenced table is huge too you will face slow delete as well

Comment: @Krismorte slower than disabling and reenabling the foreign key? Best of luck with that. 

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik yes my friend, I needed to do this sometimes to tables over the 90 million referencing other table with almost the same size. And right now I'm using the `delete top` to a partition table (SQL 2012) with more the 5 billions about four days. This is my recommendation based on my experience.

Comment: @Krismorte oh cool, how do you keep bad data from getting in while your foreign keys are disabled? Or are they untrusted and kinda useless anyway?

Comment: Simple, the downtime do drop/create the Foreing key is faster than delete with it. You can put the database restrcit user, or trust in the system. Bad data don't come from nowhere. Of course I'm talking about a eventual execution not a usually or  it may even be if we are talking about etl charges. We need more information about the environment.

Comment: Actually the main table is over 1M records with foreign key relationship to the child table with over 1B records with cascade delete constraints. Both tables logs activities for a 24/7 system. I only need to keep three months of data on both tables. Looking for advice on ways to purge the data and/or partition both tables by month and use sliding window to swap the data out.

Comment: @Krismorte you could add an answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Insert 3 month data in new table with similar structure:

> ```
> declare @CurDate datetime
> select * 
> into NewTable
> from ExistingTable 
> where datecol >= @CurDate and datecol <= dateadd(month,3,@CurDate)
> ```

2. Rename old table to anything unique or drop table as per requirement
3. Rename new table to existintg table
4. Insert into NewChildTable with similar structure which match New parent table of Step 3
5. Rename or drop existing child table
6. Rename new child table to existing child table

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

1) Save the create script of the all Foreign keys involved

```
SELECT distinct 'alter table '+rcu.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+rcu.TABLE_NAME+' add constraint '+rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME+' foreign key ('+rcu.COLUMN_NAME+') references '+rcu1.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+rcu1.TABLE_NAME+'('+rcu1.COLUMN_NAME+')'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE rcu ON rc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = rcu.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE rcu1 ON rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = rcu1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = rcu1.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where rcu.TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLE'
```

2) Dropped

```
SELECT distinct 'alter table '+rcu.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+rcu.TABLE_NAME+' drop constraint '+rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE rcu ON rc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = rcu.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE rcu1 ON rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = rcu1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = rcu1.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where rcu.TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLE'
```

3) Execute the delete like this to avoid log growing

```
declare @var bigint, @var2 bigint, @var3 bigint
set @var = (select count_big(1) from [Your_Database]..[YOUR_TABLE](nolock) --where filter if it need
set @var2 = 0
set @var3 = 1
while @var2 <> @var
begin
set rowcount 500000
    delete from [Your_Database]..[YOUR_TABLE] --where filter if it need
    set @var2 = @var2+@@ROWCOUNT
    set @var3 = @var3+1
end
```

4) Finally recreate all foriegn keys

> Just remember to run set rowcount 0 after star a new script in the
>   same session